# Why doesn't Esperanto use "neutral" days and months?

Tags: history

With its building block style, and being a new language, why did Esperanto use existing variations of days and months, instead of a neutral, generic, building block approach, for example using *Unuamonato* instead of *January*?

Comment: * Like in Chinese

Comment: Oni jam proponis tion. Ekzemple, en [La bona lingvo](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do), retejo kiu listigas _simplajn samsignifajn vortojn_, vi havas por _Januaro_ la unua monato, por Februaro la dua monato, ktp.

Answer (score 24):

It has to be remembered that the months of the Gregorian calendar aren't universal.

In the West, the first month is *January*. In the Jewish calendar, the first month is *Nisan*; in Muslim countries, the first month is *Muharram*; the first month of the Hindu calendar is *Chaitra*. None of these coincide, and in fact Muharram can occur in any season. Thus, *Januaro* is essentially a technical term in the same way that *Nisan* is. Replacing it with *unua monato* would have to be done with great caution, especially in historical texts, as January was not always considered to be the start of the year.

East Asian languages use only numbers for the Gregorian months, but it was never their practice to give names to months, and the calendar was purely administrative. Conceivably, you could invent easier-to-remember names *(Munu, Modu, Motri,* or something like that) but that starts to resemble an attempt at calendar reform, which was never a part of the Esperanto project. (Zamenhof would have been well aware of previous attempts at simplifying the calendar.) You can always write *2016.9.16* and say *du mil dek ses, punkt naŭ, punkt dek ses*.

Comment: +1 for "January was not always the start of the year"

Comment: And instead with easy "neutral" names, helping non-Europeans, it would be even more confusing to them. Esperanto has a large amount of such "naturalism". Like using germanic terms for day-month-year and romance terms for weekdays.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the issue of deciding when the year or week starts, it was after this decision that the name choice occurs.

Comment: I guess the 'optimum' solution would have been to introduce a new calendar, French Revolution-style. There they did away with traditional terms as well, but for Esperanto it would have been too much of an upheaval I suspect. And it would have turned it into an alternative culture, instead of just being the world's second language for easy communication.

Comment: "East Asian languages use only numbers for the Gregorian months, but it was never their practice to give names to months" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar#Months

Comment: Those are poetic names; "nth month" was the everyday term.

Comment: The fact that Chinese only uses numbers for months can sometimes cause ambiguities: e.g. "the fourth day of the first month" (一月四號) may refer either to the 4th of January or to the fourth day of the Chinese New Year, depending on the context.

Comment: What kinda date format is "2016.9.16"? If you use the year-month-day order in numerical Gregorian dates (which I'd highly recommend), I'd usually urge you to do so using `-` as the separator and with two-digit month and day numbers (using leading zeros to fill), so that it'd correspond to the "long" [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format: "2016-09-16". Does "2016.9.16" correspond to any Esperanto-specific format for numerical dates?

Answer (score 2):

You can write *La unua monato (de la jaro)* for January, *La dua monato (de la jaro)* for February etc. It is not common, but I don't think you will not be understood. It is probably uncommon because of the high number of syllables and people prefer shorter words.

Comment: That is probably true for almost all the language: I can say _the first month of the year_ in English or use the equivalent phrase in Italian. The question is another one, thought. Why didn't Esperanto create more generic names for months, instead of using the ones it is using?

Answer (score -2):

We already have a word for day tago. What if we could make a system there, the days of the week will all be first syllable ta plus a number 1-7 (starts at Monday) plus the last syllable go. This would make the days of the week to be as such: Taunugo, tadugo, tatrigo, takvargo, takvingo, tasesgo, tasepgo. Please notice that Esperanto, unlike English, do not write their days of the week with upper case. Wouldn't this be so much easier!

Comment: Great idea for a more radical conlang.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question

Comment: Not really answering the question.  Would be a good comment though.